# Adding a Custom Nature to Existing Android Project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Ultimately, I want to add my own custom Nature to (specifically) Android projects. For this, I want to add to the configure menu of android projects: Add Shush Nature, and Remove Shush Nature. However, I do not seem to be able of doing this to Android nor to Java projects.

I supposed that android projects (according to their .project) has the nature: `com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature`.

Therefore I created two definitions:

```
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions">
<definition
    id="test.androidProjectNature">
    <with variable="selection">
        <iterate operator="or" ifEmpty="false">
           <test
                 property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature"
                 value="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature">
           </test>
        </iterate>
    </with>
</definition>
<definition
    id="test.shushProject">
    <with variable="selection">
        <iterate operator="or" ifEmpty="false">
           <test
                 property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature"
                 value="mobi.shush.plugin.nature">
           </test>
        </iterate>
    </with>
</definition>
```

Supposedly, definition `test.androidProjectNature` will test whether the project is an Android project and `test.shushProject` will test whether the project has my custom nature.

My problem is that I am unable to make the following command what so ever:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.projectConfigure?after=additions">
     <command
           commandId="Shush-Plugin.addRemoveShushNature"
           label="Disable Shush Nature"
           style="push">
        <visibleWhen>
            <reference 
                definitionId="test.shushProject">
            </reference>
        </visibleWhen>  
     </command>
     <command
           commandId="Shush-Plugin.addRemoveShushNature"
           label="Enable Shush Nature"
           style="push">
        <visibleWhen>
            <reference 
                definitionId="test.androidProjectNature">
            </reference>
        </visibleWhen>  
     </command>
  </menuContribution>
```

Enable Shush Nature is appearing on projects created using **New > Project** (not java project). It seems to me that this problem is not directly related to android because of the fact that this is not appearing on java projects even if I add a check to the `org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature`. On another note, the default extension sample for builder and nature seems to add the two menus to projects (again) created by **New > Project** only.

Comment: Thank you for this constructive comment. @Ahmad

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems something of a cast problem or so.

The whole idea is to use `<adapt>` to be able to check the IProject instance.

```
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions">
<definition
    id="test.androidProjectNature">
    <with variable="selection">
        <iterate operator="or" ifEmpty="false">
          <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
               <test
                     property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature"
                     value="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature">
               </test>
          </adapt>
        </iterate>
    </with>
</definition>
<definition
    id="test.shushProject">
    <with variable="selection">
        <iterate operator="or" ifEmpty="false">
          <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
               <test
                     property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature"
                     value="com.shush.plugin.nature">
               </test>
          </adapt>
        </iterate>
    </with>
</definition>
```